# Split an array-object into multiple array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to split an array-object that has an array as attribute into multiple objects, each one with one element of the previous array. I'm working in a js class The idea is coded below:

```
class Example {

  async ArraySplitter(){ 

    this.Array=[ 
      { name:something,
        features:[feature1,feature2,...]
      }]

      //Which becomes:

    this.Array=[
      { name:something,
        features:feature1
      },
      { name:something,
        features:feature2
      }''
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why is this `async`?

Comment: it is just part of a longer code which needs the function to be async

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating objects by splitting an object whose attributes are arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392092/creating-objects-by-splitting-an-object-whose-attributes-are-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do a 1-n mapping. It can be done via [looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), or via [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Here is a sample code to help with (believe it is self-explanatory):

```js
// Entity representing an element, with its own features
class Element {
  constructor(name, features) {
    this.name = name;
    this.features = features;
  }

  get featureMap() {

    // Option 1: Looping 
    const map = [];
    this.features.forEach((feature) => {
      map.push({
        name: this.name,
        feature: feature
      });
    });
    return map;

    // Option 2: Map
    return this.features.map(feature => {
      return {
        name: this.name,
        feature: feature
      }
    });
  }
}

// Test 1: Get element mapped to its features
const candleElement = new Element("Candle", ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]);
console.log(candleElement.featureMap);

// Test 2: Get element mapped to its features
const roseElement = new Element("Rose", ["Red", "Green"]);
console.log(roseElement.featureMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `reduce` over our original array.
Inside that reduce we will `map` the sub array and emit the desired object.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "test1",
  values: ["t1", "t2"]
},
{
  name: "test2",
  values: ["t3", "t4"]
}];

const flat = arr.reduce((a, {name, values}) => {
   a.push(
     values.map(
       value => ({ name, value })
    )
  );
  return a;
}, []).flatMap(x => x);

console.log(`Flat: ${JSON.stringify(flat)}`);
```

Comment: In this way we would create several arrays right? Is it possible to mantain the objects in the same array?

Comment: Yup, just added the flat map. Or you could forEach => push.

Comment: what if also the attribute "name" was an array and I wanted to split it as you did with "values"?

Comment: You already picked another answer.